# Postgres unique index conflict on insert

Tags: postgresql, nested-sets

I have a table with a nested set so each row has a lft & rgt value.
When a new row is inserted into the table the nodes following need to have their lft & rgt values incremented by 2 and then the new node can be inserted.

I have an index on both the lft & rgt columns however as these values are unique I wanted to use a unique index.

When inserting a new node the unique index fails advising that the lft value violates the index as it appears the index is checked before the update statement completes. So when a value is incremented by 2 it conflicts before the others can also be incremented by 2.

Is there a way to ignore the index until after the update statement has been completed?

**Edit1**

For example if I added a child node under "Languages" then its lft & rgt values would be: 4 & 5 and therefore the following nodes would need to be incremented by 2 to make room for the new node.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a flawed design.  If this is a tree, then I should be able to add a new node without renumbering all of the other nodes.

Comment: Post your table description (ddl script) and example data - all as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) - **no images**. Also, why do you think you need to increase existing values to insert a node?

Comment: I guess the order of your updates is not compatible with this unique index. If you want to stay with the nested set structure and the unique constraint, then you need to reorder them. I think starting at the end might be useful here and then traversing the boundaries towards the start (so it is like a backwards infix traversal, I guess). But as others already said, perhaps rethink if this structure is appropriate. It is surely not if you have much manipulation of data (```INSERT```, ```UPDATE``` or ```DELETE```).

Comment: You might also defer the checking of your ```UNIQUE``` constraint, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html

Comment: @Islingre You are correct updating from back to front would work but how do I order an update statement?

Comment: Too complex and error prone. I personally wouldn’t use a model like this, I would go for a much simpler model that just points to a parent_id

Comment: I do not know if this is possible (if you want to keep it in one query). Perhaps have a look on the deferring statement I mentioned above. Defer the constraint before your update and reset it to immediate afterwards (or just wait until the end of your transaction).
But as others said: check if your model makes sense for your use cases. I would usually take the approach mentioned by @FrankHeikens and establish a "foreign" key (yes, a foreign key might point to a table it is defined on) to the parent.

Comment: This is why I don’t want to use it, and why a CTE is a simpler solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 0):

First: Check if your model is appropriate! Nested sets are inappropriate if you have much manipulation of data (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`).

Second: If you want to stay with nested sets, you might defer the validation of the `UNIQUE` constraint. The documentation for this can be found at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html